# String equality using is

Tags: python, string, string-comparison

Would somebody please be able to explain the following behaviour in Python:

```
>>> 'a' * 20 is 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
True

>>> 'a' * 21 is 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
False
```

I would expect the second case to be also `True`. This example is taken from the [wtfpython repo](https://github.com/satwikkansal/wtfpython#-strings-can-be-tricky-sometimes-), which is a collection of snippets with "surprising" behaviours. There is [an open issue](https://github.com/satwikkansal/wtfpython/issues/67) about a missing explanation for this particular snippet, though given the context I assume this has to do with "interning" strings. Your explanations would go towards submitting a PR, thanks!

Comment: [Duplicate]
This is very nicely explained on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/why-does-comparing-strings-in-python-using-either-or-is-sometimes-produce

Comment: @ApurvaN.Saraogi To make sure I understand, in this particular case, the issue is the use of `is` (identity comparison) instead of `==` (equality test) as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1504848/472610), correct?

Comment: @Sheljohn Correct. In the `False` example that you've posted, `id('a'*21) != id('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa')`.